# Get element value from multiple table rows generated by js

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-table

I'm generating table in html using js, each row contain two drop down and 1 test box, each drop down has onchange function, my prob is how can I get first drop down selected value when second drop down is choose in second drop down onchange function.

I tried the below code:

```
  var r = document.getElementById('AACTVTbl').getElementsByTagName('td')[idx-1].document.getElementById("division").value;
alert(idx+" "+r);
```

but just get value from 1st row only.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you paste all of the code? This snippet is out of context and makes it difficult to assess exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, finally found solution,

```
idx= this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex
var selectedDivisionId=ele.form.division[idx-1].value;
```